# What approach method does tower possible to give me?

Tags: air-traffic-control

I'm a student pilot. ATC is a difficult part for me.
So far when I fly cross-country, the only VFR approach I hear from ATC is "straight to runway XX". Is there any other approach the ATC will instruct me? What are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an excellent question to **ask your instructor**. They can sit down with you and discuss the various possible pattern entries: what you can expect ATC to say and what you would do with the airplane in response. And you can ask to fly with your instructor to towered airports and practice different entries.

What country are you flying in? In the [usa](/questions/tagged/usa), the [AIM 4–3–2](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap4_section_3.html#%24paragraph4-3-2) provides a general overview of operations at towered airports—that entire section would be a good read. ATC follows a different document, JO 7110.65; pilots are not required to be intimately familiar with the 7110.65 (just as ATC is not required to be intimately familiar with the AIM) but if you know where to look you can gain some good insight and learn what phraseology you can expect to hear on the radio. The [.65 3–10–1](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap3_section_10.html) lists phraseology to be used when specifying pattern information (and [see also 3–8–1](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap3_section_8.html)):

> ***PHRASEOLOGY-***
> *ENTER LEFT/RIGHT BASE.*
> *STRAIGHT-IN.*
> *MAKE STRAIGHT-IN.*
> *STRAIGHT-IN APPROVED.*
> *RIGHT TRAFFIC.*
> *MAKE RIGHT TRAFFIC.*
> *RIGHT TRAFFIC APPROVED.*
> *CONTINUE.*
> ***NOTE-***
> *Additional information should normally be issued with instructions to continue. Example:
> "continue, report one mile final"; "continue, expect landing clearance two mile final"; etc.*

The Pilot/Controller Glossary is also a very good source of information; for example the entry for [TRAFFIC PATTERN](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-t.html#%24TRAFFIC%20PATTERN) includes these helpful notes:

> *ATC may instruct a pilot to report a "2−mile left base" to Runway 22. This instruction means that the pilot is expected to maneuver their aircraft into a left base leg that will intercept a straight−in final 2 miles from the approach end of Runway 22 and advise ATC.*
> *ATC may instruct a pilot to report "5−mile final" to Runway 22. This instruction means that the pilot should maneuver their aircraft onto a straight−in final and advise ATC when they are five miles from the approach end of Runway 22.*

Note that in the absence of a specific pattern entry instruction, the default expectation (just as at a non-towered airport) is that you will enter the pattern by way of the downwind. However, you should be very certain to ask if they intend you to cross over the airport in order to enter the "correct" downwind; it is always better to ask for clarification than to make assumptions. In my experience it is more often intended that you will enter the closest downwind, even if that is not the "correct" downwind per the Chart Supplement.

Comment: It's so good to know where to find what ATC could possibly say.
I know I can discuss with CFI but it' hard to discuss with CFI for all circumstances. Thank you very much for the references

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to get the ATIS information early, and to understand your position in relation to the runway in use.

ATIS information will usually say which runway is in use.  Knowing that and knowing where you are in relation can help you anticipate what the tower's instructions will likely be.

One of the busy towered airports I fly into as a GA VFR pilot often gives me instructions to either enter right downwind for runway 34R, enter right base for 34R or report the shoreline for a straight in 16L.  All based on where I'm at in relation to the field and how busy the pattern is.